# How to insert xul panel so doesn't minimize with window

Tags: firefox-addon, panel, xul

I create a panel and insert it into the id mainPopupSet area of the most recent navigator:browser window. I set the level to top so it shows over everything. But if that window closes the panel  goes, also if that window minimizes it screws with the panel.

Is there anywhere I can insert it so it doesn't minmize? And will only disappear when Firefox exists?

Comment: This behavior must be dependent on the operating system, I don't see it on OS X.

Comment: Ah I use Windows XP SP2. I filed a bug report awhile ago about this but got no replies yet [HERE](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=976438)