# Always on Top Panel XUL Element

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

Hi all I wanted to make a xul panel that is always on top. Is this possible?

This is my code so far but it doesnt work so well, can run from scratchpad:

If user minimizes the firefox window I added the panel goes with it. If user closes the window i added it to panel goes with it. On maximize/restore of minimized window the panel location gets all messed up and it flashes and stuff. I tried to add to `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow` but i ran into all kinds of problems.

```
var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
var panel = win.document.createElement('panel');
var screen = Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.screen;
var props = {
    noautohide: true,
    noautofocus: false,
    level: 'top',
    style: 'padding:15px; margin:0; width:200px; height:200px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); -moz-pointer-events:none; border:0; -moz-appearance:none !important;'
}
for (var p in props) {
    panel.setAttribute(p, props[p]);
}

panel.addEventListener('dblclick',function() {
    panel.parentNode.removeChild(panel);
}, false);


win.document.querySelector('#mainPopupSet').appendChild(panel);

panel.openPopup(null, 'overlap', screen.availLeft, screen.availTop);
```

double click panel to remove it

Comment: Please provide a better description than "doesn't work." It seems to work pretty well for me, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Ah you're right I forgot to explain how it doesnt work haha. So basically if I minimize the window I added it to or close the window the panel goes with it. I tried adding panel to a hiddenDOMWindow which doesnt close till Firefox actually quits but it didn't work :( Thanks so much for help wlad! :) No one else replies to my topics :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert xul panel so doesn't minimize with window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926453/how-to-insert-xul-panel-so-doesnt-minimize-with-window)

Comment: ah yeah its my own topic :( i tried to narrow it down there because i was't getting any replies. or i tried to include example in this topic to try to get replies :(