# alternative to panel in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

Is there any alternative to "panel" in firefox extension in 
this I want to show popup in firefox add-on  and also I want to populate it using a GET request to server but I'm unable to access the id element in my htm id's  in that 
and why  'document' is not recognizable in firefox extension whenever I use

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `iframe` in the panel. Then load into the `iframe`. For example: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9445992

just add an iframe to that panel

Other option is to make a `window`: [How to insert xul panel so doesn't minimize with window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926453/how-to-insert-xul-panel-so-doesnt-minimize-with-window/22121685#22121685)

edit: or use addon sdk panels which has the iframe automatically